# ¿Este media player es obsoleto? ¿Hay alguna forma más actual y que mejore el rendimiento?

Tags: android, android-studio, mediaplayer

Tengo una app que reproduce música en directo en stream. Funciona correctamente. Soy nuevo en android studio y por lo que estoy viendo tengo dudas de si el código que estoy usando es eficiente o si hay alguna mejor forma de reescribirlo.

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var BPlayPause: Button
    private  lateinit var Mplayer: MediaPlayer


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlayPause)
        button.setOnClickListener { startService(Intent(applicationContext, MyService::class.java)) }

        BPlayPause = findViewById(R.id.buttonPlayPause)
        RadioOndaCero()
    }

    private fun RadioOndaCero(){
        val url = "http://mi-direccion-servidor-streaming"
        Mplayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
//            setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .build()
            )
            reset()
            setDataSource(url)
            prepare()
        }
        Mplayer.setOnPreparedListener {
            PlayOnda(this)
        }
    }

    private fun PlayOnda(context: Context){

        BPlayPause.setOnClickListener {
            if (Mplayer.isPlaying){
                Mplayer.pause()
                BPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_round)
                // Toast.makeText(context, "En Pause...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else
            {
                Mplayer.start()
                BPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_round)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    fun openBrowser(view: View) {

        //Get url from tag
        val url = view.getTag() as String
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)

        //pass the url to intent data
        intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxxx.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Radio">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Para ejecutar en segundo plano tengo esto MyService.kt

```
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.widget.Toast
class MyService : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        onTaskRemoved(intent)
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext, "This is a Service running in Background",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        return START_STICKY
    }
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented")
    }
    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent) {
        val restartServiceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, this.javaClass)
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(packageName)
        startService(restartServiceIntent)
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
    }
}
```

Comment: "No abre en 30 para arriba" que se muestra en el LogCat? es importante agregues esta información

Comment: He corregido la compatibilidad con API 30 en adelante. Mi cuestión la edito para conocer si hay alguna forma más eficiente de código.

Comment: Pero cuál era el error en el LogCat?